# Calling WNetAddConnection2 with empty local name

Tags: c++, wnet

I have a small program that simply checks if a specified file is located on a specified network drive that is not mapped on the computer.

To check this I temporarily map to the network location, check if the file exists and than unmap the drive. I now figured out that I can call WNetAddConnection2 with an empty local name (MSDN: If the string is empty, or if lpLocalName is NULL, the function makes a connection to the network resource without redirecting a local device.).

Just for showing the code:

```
NETRESOURCE nr;
nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
nr.lpLocalName = NULL; // explicitly set this to NULL
nr.lpRemoteName = "\\\\computer\\c$";
nr.lpProvider = NULL;

DWORD dwResult = WNetAddConnection2(&nr, cstrPassword, cstrUsername, FALSE);
if (dwResult != 0)
{
    return false;
}

CPath cLocation(cstrFileLocation);
return cLocation.FileExists() != FALSE;
```

So far so good the code works fine. But what I now want to know is if there is any problem with that call of WNetAddConnection2? I cannot call WNetCancelConnection, as I do not have a local name. So do I have some kind of zombies on my computer now?

How can I see all my network connections on my computer? Best would be a short command for the Command Prompt (something like NET USE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. I can call `WNetCancelConnection2(nr.lpRemoteName, 0, TRUE);` to unmap the drive properly.